# how to download file from a link, and the name contains "%"

Tags: html, http, url, href

**File name** : File 1%.txt

```
   <a  href="File 1%.txt" download="File 1%.txt">File 1%.txt</a>
```

If I remove "%" from the name then this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?:

```
<a  href="File 1%.txt" download="File 1\%.txt">File 1%.txt</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are file systems that [won't allow a % character in filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits). Anyhow, I recommend you [urlencode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the parameters as follows:

```
<a href="File%201%25.txt" download>File 1%.txt</a>
```